Trying to dual boot Ubuntu with pre-installed Win11
I am trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop with pre-installed Win11.
In the manual selection, it is showing the complete physical drive which is 2XNVMe SSD drives (2TB). The Laptop has 11th generation Intel CPU, comes with Intel VMD that treat storage as RAID0.
If I went a head with "Install alongside Windows Boot Manager", will it delete Windows since there are no Logical drives? or it will take the free space I just allocated by shrinking my C Drive?
Has anyone come across a problem like this, knowing I couldn't disable Intel VMD from BIOS because It won't recognize the RAID0 cluster that has Windows Boot Manager on.
I have attached two screenshots.
BIOS
Partitions on Ubuntu Installer
Appreciate any help or suggestions.

I forgot to make all the changes I normally recommend to others when installing to my Dell with 11th Gen Intel and Windows 11. It only had one NVMe drive but had Intel VMD. Ubuntu then installed using the VMD driver where normally we have to change to AHCI. I did have to turn bitlocker & Windows fast start up so drive seen correctly. RAID 0 typically not recommended. If one drive fails you lose all data. Used on systems with slow HDDs and only for compiling  or other CPU/drive intensive applications & data stored on separate server. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2435221
